# Customize onepage/success url with observer

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, url, redirect

I must to add order_id to url of onepage/success page,  I write this code, but it appears to be not working.

```
         <events>
            <controller_front_init_routers>
                <observers>
                    <dk_images>
                        <!-- <type>singleton</type> -->
                        <class>DK_Images_Controller_Router</class>
                        <method>initControllerRouters</method>
                    </dk_images>
                </observers>
            </controller_front_init_routers>    
        </events>
```

and controller

```
<?php
class DK_Images_Controller_Router extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Abstract 
{
    public function initControllerRouters($observer)
    {
        $front = $observer->getEvent()->getFront();
        $front->addRouter('checkout/onepage', $this);
        return $this;
    }

    public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request)
    {  


        if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('install'))
                ->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
        $urlKey = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();//trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');

        $parts = explode('/', $urlKey);

        if (count($parts) < 3) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($parts[5] == 'onepage' && $parts[6] == 'success') {

            $lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
                   ->getLastRealOrderId();

            $request->setModuleName('checkout')
                    ->setControllerName('onepage')
                    ->setActionName('success')
                    ->setParam('id', $lastOrderId);
            $request->setAlias(
                Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
                $urlKey
            );
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats do you want to achieve ?

Comment: I want change onepage/success url from .../checkout/onepage/success/ to .../checkout/onepage/success/order_id=10000000001